# How do I add a custom Devise/Warden authentication strategy for use with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: devise, activeadmin, warden, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to build a SSO system where a bunch of Rails 4 apps under different subdomains share a common cookie. I've got 4 apps doing authentication via the sorcery gem and 2 apps using ActiveAdmin and Devise.

The 4 apps using Sorcery are working as expected, I can get a successfully signed on user to access all 4 different apps using the same session cookie.

I'm having trouble with the 2 Devise/ActiveAdmin apps. I added a custom Warden authentication strategy and configured Devise to use it. But I don't think the strategy is being used because I continue to get 401 unauthorized errors and any puts statements/logging in the authenticate! method below is never seen. Anyone with previous experience doing this? Or maybe some help tracing through where the authentication steps are happening so I can try to add some logging?

```
Warden::Strategies.add(:gc_auth) do
  def valid?
    true
  end

  def authenticate!
    user = AdminUser.find_by_uuid(session[:user_uuid])
    user ? success!(user) : fail!("Not signed in") 
  end
end



config.warden do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies.unshift :gc_auth
end
```

Comment: Hmm....seems like I have to do something like this: http://4trabes.com/2012/10/31/remote-authentication-with-devise/

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get this to work by examining how this gem is structured:

https://github.com/AMekss/devise_custom_authenticatable